# ANT eclipse and buildpath

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant

I have a project in Eclipse and I use pom file in order to import my class:

```
<groupId>fr.moon.verify</groupId>
    <artifactId>verify</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>verify</name>
```

and to create a war.

My problem that I have another classes in another folders inside to eclipse

```
src/wolf/create/[classes]
src1/wolf1/create1/[classes]
```

and every time that I pass the project in an another pc, I have to import these classes in a manual mode.

Is there a system using POM or ANT to import my class in an automatically way?

Thank you for your help!

My pom is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>fr.moon.verify</groupId>
        <artifactId>verify</artifactId>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>verify</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>verify</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId> <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- added to retrieve server path -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId> 
            <version>3.1.0</version> <scope>provided</scope> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160212</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.22.1</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: As far as i know maven requires exact files structure, which you should keep in order to make it work

Comment: I add my pom file if is useful.

Comment: I mean -  try following [this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) rules, and everything will be easier.

Comment: Oh, sorry, i just got it, you are importing war and it misses some files, well, why don't you include those in your war if you need them? Otherwise how will another computer's maven knows anything about your computer's files

Comment: I have a project in eclipse with all the files, these files are stored in the eclipse (no in another pc). But when a copy my project  in another pc (by pen drive for instance) I have to import some files by the `Build Path -> Use as Source Folder` of eclipse.

Comment: Well, then it leads us to my first comment and you should be using maven directory layout, then i think eclipse will automatically import your files

Comment: My problem that I cannot change the directory of these classes, so I wish to find a ant script or some thing else about pom

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have java files for those classes. You can add additional source folder using [build helper plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html).

If you only have access to the classes, then you should add dependency to your project.

1. [create](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/step2.html) a jar file using those classes.
2. [Install](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) that jar in your maven repository.
3. Better option that step 2 is to upload it in your repository manager like artifactory or nexus, if you use one.
4. Add this jar dependency on your project.

Comment: I'm not able to insert these classes in my pom, can you show me an simple example? Thank you. I have not any `<groupId>it.polito.escape</groupId>
 <artifactId></artifactId>
 <packaging></packaging>
 <version></version>
 <name></name>` but single class inside a folder.